# Performance improvement Outer Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which runs slower.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Obe].[dbo].[vFan] P 
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 [CT_XY] 
     FROM [Obe].[dbo].[vFan] 
     WHERE [row_num] <= P.[row_num] 
       AND [CT_XY] IS NOT NULL 
       AND [CT_XY] != 0 
     ORDER BY [row_num] DESC) Q
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 [CT_CR1]  
     FROM [Obe].[dbo].[vFan] 
     WHERE [row_num] <= P.[row_num] 
       AND [CT_CR1] IS NOT NULL 
       AND [CT_CR1] != 0 
     ORDER BY [row_num] DESC) R
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 [CT_CR2] 
     FROM [Obe].[dbo].[vFan] 
     WHERE [row_num] <= P.[row_num] 
       AND [CT_CR2] IS NOT NULL 
       AND [CT_CR2] != 0 
     ORDER BY [row_num] DESC) S
ORDER BY 
    P.[row_num] ASC
```

Order By inside the Outer Apply is very costly, is there any better way to write this query ?

Comment: Sample data, desired results and and explanation of the logic would all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell in the code, you seem to be implementing a variation of `lag(ignore nulls)`.

Here is a better way:

```
select f.*,
       max(ct_xy) over (partition by rn_xy) as new_ct_xy,
       max(rn_cr1) over (partition by rn_cr1) as new_rn_cr1,
       max(rn_cr2) over (partition by rn_cr2) as new_rn_cr2
from (select f.*,
             sum(case when CT_XY is not null and CT_XY <> 0 
                      then row_num
                 end) over (order by row_num) as rn_xy,
             sum(case when CT_CR1 is not null and CT_CR1 <> 0 
                      then row_num
                 end) over (order by row_num) as rn_cr1,
             sum(case when CT_CR2 is not null and CT_CR2 <> 0 
                      then row_num
                 end) over (order by row_num) as rn_cr2
      from vfan f 
     ) f;
```

Also note that in many databases the "v" in `vfan` would suggest a view.  That might be the cause of the performance issues.

Comment: Yes i am doing lag(ignore nulls and zeros) but the query you have given is not taking lag

Comment: @Jayasree . . . It should be taking the previous valid value for each row.  However, if you set up a db<>fiddle, it would be possible for me to better understand your data and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ORDER BY`, SQL Server must compute all rows, sort then and only then can it give you the rows that you asked for.

So it would be great to add indexes for fields used in `WHERE` statement such as `CT_XY`, `CT_CR1`, `CT_CR2`.

UPDATE:

You should not add indexes to view, it is necessary to add indexes to the underlying table. Your query will use the indexes, where appropriate, on the underlying tables the view itself refers to.

Comment: Since it is a view column i cannot create index.

Comment: CT_XY,CT_CR1,CT_CR2 columns are calculated and created in the view at runtime. Not present in parent table

Comment: @Jayasree as Gordon Linoff said `Sample data, desired results and and explanation of the logic would all help`